# Python scipy / Fortran : float64, real, double?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, type-conversion

I am writing a front-end in Python for a Fortran library. The Python modules are supposed to work on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines; for windows, linux and mac.

I would like to get some clarity on the byte widths of some of the data types:

[1] Say a variable in the Fortran function is declared as "real". Is this always 8-byte wide for both 32-bit and 64-bit machines?

[2] What is the difference between scipy.float64 and scipy.double? Are they identical for all machines?

Reliable answers from experts on this topic would help very much.

Comment: This may help: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Comment: I cannot answer the second, but the first one is alluded to there: http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Real+precision Essentially, it is possible to do it that way, but if you only write `real`, the result is compiler dependent.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [241]: np.double
Out[241]: numpy.float64


In [246]: x=np.float64(34)
In [247]: x
Out[247]: 34.0
In [248]: x.nbytes
Out[248]: 8
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.config.html
Docs for system configuration constants

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/misc.html#interfacing-to-fortran

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/